# Why do the html controls in below page wrap when browser resized

Tags: css, html, browser

Below is code for a simple HTML page.
Despite the overflow and white-space settings in the style for container, the controls will wrap when the page is re-sized. I am testing in Chrome browser.

Seems to be solved by adding a float:left also to the container style. But I am curious as to why the wrap happens in the first place? I really don't want to float the container to left since it may cause other complications.

```css
#container {
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.tmplLabelHorizontal {
  float: left;
}

.tmplLabelHorizontalWithLeftSpacing {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">

  <div id="tmplTabShiftPanelRow1">

    <label class="tmplLabelHorizontal">Start Time:</label>

    <div style="float:left">
      <input maxLength="8" style="width:60px; " type="text" />
    </div>

    <label class="tmplLabelHorizontalWithLeftSpacing">Start Time:</label>

    <div style="float:left">
      <input maxLength="8" style="width:60px; " type="text" />
    </div>

    <label class="tmplLabelHorizontalWithLeftSpacing">Start Time:</label>

    <div style="float:left">
      <input maxLength="8" style="width:60px; " type="text" />
    </div>


    <label class="tmplLabelHorizontalWithLeftSpacing">Start Time:</label>

    <div style="float:left">
      <input maxLength="8" style="width:60px; " type="text" />
    </div>


    <label class="tmplLabelHorizontalWithLeftSpacing">Start Time:</label>

    <div style="float:left">
      <input maxLength="8" style="width:60px; " type="text" />
    </div>

    <label class="tmplLabelHorizontalWithLeftSpacing">Start Time:</label>

    <div style="float:left">
      <input maxLength="8" style="width:60px; " type="text" />
    </div>

    <label class="tmplLabelHorizontalWithLeftSpacing">Start Time:</label>

    <div style="float:left">
      <input maxLength="8" style="width:60px; " type="text" />
    </div>


    <label class="tmplLabelHorizontalWithLeftSpacing">Start Time:</label>

    <div style="float:left">
      <input maxLength="8" style="width:60px; " type="text" />
    </div>



  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the style

```
word-wrap: normal;
```

Answer (score 0):

`white-space` affects inline elements and text, not floating elements.

Try using `display:inline-block` instead of `float:left`.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way is wrapping the label inside the div like that.

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="tmplTabShiftPanelRow1">
        <div style="float:left">
            <label class="tmplLabelHorizontal">Start Time:</label>
            <input maxLength="8" style="width:60px; " type="text" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Applying float:left works for me like I said. But my question is if there is a different way to accomplish this rather than float the container?

Comment: I edited the example, you aren't floating the container you are just wrapping the label and input together so if the screen size change they will move together and will not split.

Answer (score 0):

Div is block element. So if you will not specify any `float` value these will not be wrapped. A work around to make the divs wrapped is add `display: inline` or `display:inline-block`, so that they will not behave like block elements.

Well another solution is use `spans` instead of `divs` if you don't need divs. Span is not block element, so they will wrap automatically.